# Object of class Layout could not be converted to string

Tags: php, radphp

When I run the app locally via the IDE I do not see any errors

But when transferred to a server I get
"Object of class Layout could not be converted to string in / *folder location* /rpcl/classes.inc.php on line 484"

This is stopping me deploying so any help would be gratefully received.
I have transferred the whole RPCL library onto the server (except the specialist folders such as Google / Facebook)

I'm running RadPHP XE2 fully patched

Comment: I removed the Delphi tag. Use that for Delphi Pascal questions.

Answer (score 0):

this was a corruption of the form within RadPHP
I created a new project with a form then copied all the objects and code from the old one.
Finally I put the new form.php and form.xml.php back into the original project and hey presto it worked!
Not really a solution but as HTML5 Builder is now available whatever it was is not going to be fixed in RadPHP

Answer (score -1):

This problem still occurs with html5 builder.

Problem occurs when you change any layout or font properties on the form at design time.  This gives in the form file the structure

```
<property>
  <property ..>stuff</property>
  <property ..>stuff</property>
</property>
```

So the painful work-arround is not to change class properties such as layout or font at design time.